# How to configure DNS record for allow email sending from different domain

Tags: email, dns, spf, dkim, sender-id

Hello everyone I'm Italian and I apologize in advance for errors that read as follows :)

I'm starting to use a newsletter service (easymail-pro .it) that sends email using my domain name but by a different host. 
I need to istall the dkim and spf records that have sended me, but when I install the records, all email that i send directly by my domain go to spam.
My records are:

```
TXT - key_14046._domainkey.domainname.agency - v=DKIM1; k=rsa; - 300
TXT - domainname.agency - v=spf1 a mx ~all - 300
```

I don't know what key_14046 mean, many time ago when i started to configure mail server, mail-tester .com suggested me to add this record and it worked fine

These are the record that easymail-pro .it say me to install

```
SPF:    domainname.agency IN TXT "spf2.0/pra include:x6h***1.com ~all"
DKIM: v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA***************************gQDPQsoOji9HBmGxtkyU4BqLBAsCN/cJfJp+6vbMazf88I4KRKYw80kYoXl6EME0tubD4VHhK6Mmj*****************7DlcIxQIDAQAB
```

When I add the records of easymail-pro .it my email goes spam and when i test my email with mail-tester .com i receive many error.

if i add more than one spf record not working so I've tried to mix SPF in this way "v=spf1 a mx include:x6h***1.com ~all" but still not working

What is the way to configure correctly the DNS Record??

Answer (score 0):

In the authoritative DNS for your domain:

```
your.domain.here    IN  TXT "spf2.0/pra include:x6h***1.com ~all"
                IN  TXT "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA***************************gQDPQsoOji9HBmGxtkyU4BqLBAsCN/cJfJp+6vbMazf88I4KRKYw80kYoXl6EME0tubD4VHhK6Mmj*****************7DlcIxQIDAQAB"
```

[Domain Key how-to](http://www.gettingemaildelivered.com/dkim-explained-how-to-set-up-and-use-domainkeys-identified-mail-effectively)

[SPF how-to](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch9/spf.html), and

[Sender ID](http://www.activecampaign.com/sender-id/)

Comment: okay this was my first try but mail-tester says me error because there are 2 spf records. Another question: for Dkim in the host field i must put  key_14046._domainkey.domainname.agency or only domainname.agency?

Comment: it's been a while since I had to deal with DKIM, but if the ESP has given you settings for it, then you should use those. Since it's a PKI based service that signs messages, there is mail server side configuration that needs to be matched by your DNS entries.

Comment: Resolution: the problem was the provider newsletter. They had no expected domains .agency